# Syntax highlight for Stdout and Stderr

Tags: shell, web-applications, stdout, syntax-highlighting

I'm developing an application that runs some shell commands, and I want to print the shell output in my web app in a pretty way. I tried some syntax highlighters, but it doesn't recognize the colors or break lines for example.

Here is an output example:

```
FAIL tmp/jest_client/0052ba7f-1c68-4f16-924f-5d44fa0ea415.test.js (5.511s)↵ some↵ ✕ returns 2 (3ms)↵↵ ● some › returns 2↵↵ ReferenceError: some is not defined↵ ↵ at Object.<anonymous> (tmp/jest_client/0052ba7f-1c68-4f16-924f-5d44fa0ea415.test.js:5:11)↵↵Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total↵Tests: 1 failed, 1 total↵Snapshots: 0 total↵Time: 13.869s↵Ran all test suites matching /tmp/jest_client/0052ba7f-1c68-4f16-924f-5d44fa0ea415.test.js/i.↵
```

Thaks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I used the **[aha](https://github.com/theZiz/aha)** Linux package.